# Is a creature that has an adventure considered a creature with no abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's use [Tuinvale Treefolk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=473142) as the creature for this example as it has no abilities on its creature side.

This is relevant for [Ruxa, Patient Professor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=521662) and [Muraganda Petroglyphs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?multiverseid=130614).

Does the answer change when the creature is in the graveyard? (this is relevant for Ruxa's first ability)

What about in the hand, in case a card existed that let you put a creature with no abilities into the batlefield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, in all cases the creature is considered to have no abilities.

[Comprehensive Rules 716.4](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220610.pdf) states:

> In every zone except the stack, and while on the stack not as an
> Adventure, an adventurer card has only its normal characteristics.

Meaning in the battlefield, graveyard, hand and otherwise the adventure side would be ignored and the creature part has indeed no abilities.

Comment: As always, I feel it would be better to reference the actual CR (716.4 in this case) rather than the ruling; Wizards are notorious for the haphazard nature of whether a ruling appears in Gatherer or not.

Comment: It's [715.4](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr715/)

Comment: some list it as 716.4, like https://mtg.wtf/help/rules and the [mtg fandom page](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure) but the [downloadable document](https://media.wizards.com/2021/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020210419.pdf) form wizards has it as 715.4

Comment: I couldn't edit my previous comment but I'm thinking the document could be outdated. The judge blog agreeing with it led me to believe it's the true one. My doubt is that the other links have rule 707 and these two don't, that's why their number is one higher, so they could be newer (also, the rules document form wizards does say 2021), fandom page says there was an update with Baldur's Gate in June 10, 2022

Comment: @Chebi You're linking to last year's rules (19th April 2021, as per the 20210419 in the URL). In the [most recent rules](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220610.pdf), CR 715 is Sagas.

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks mate, the judge's blog being off as well threw me off

Comment: [ Not that it really matters but the rule that was added was "706 Rolling a die", probably as part of the AFR update; everything above that was renumbered ]